# JavaScript line break encoding in template literals

Tags: javascript, encoding, axios, line-breaks, template-literals

In template literals, line breaks can be represented with `\n` or with literal line breaks in the string. According to documentation and from printing to console, there is no difference between these two methods.

However, when working with Axios, I sent a string over with with the `\n` in the data field of POST. The server interpreted this request incorrectly and merged the lines in the string. When I changed all the `\n` characters with literal line breaks in the string, the server interpreted the request as expected. What is going on here? Is there a difference in encoding between the two methods?

```
// this works
    await axios.post(`${myURL}/`, {
            password: `${username}@${server}
            ${password}`
        });

// this doesn't work
    await axios.post(`${myURL}/`, {
            password: `${username}@${server}\n${password}`
        });
```

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools _Network_ panel to inspect the request payloads and the responses for each. What are the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a difference in encoding between the two methods?

Yes, your first code also includes a number of non-newline spaces between the server and the password:

```
            ${password}`
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To make them identical, add spaces after the `\n`, something like:

```
await axios.post(`${myURL}/`, {
        password: `${username}@${server}\n             ${password}`
    });
```

(you might only need one additional space after the \n for it to be parsed properly - experiment a bit)

Comment: I don't think this is the case. When I just typed the string out using a string literal and no extra spaces, I was able to get the correct result. For example, password: "myUsername@theServer\nThePassword". The difference was specifically only seen when including `\n` in template literals. I.e., I could use the exact same string as "myUsername@theServer\nThePassword" and just replace quotes with back ticks to get a template literal and see a different result.

Comment: @dz210 compare your strings then. What does `console.log("myUsername@theServer\nThePassword" === \`${username}@${server}\n${password}\`)` produce?

Comment: @dz210 Other than those spaces, your strings are identical. Something else might be causing the problem, maybe a server error? Check the payload of the request and the response

Comment: @Phil that returns true. That's why this was so confusing to me.

Comment: So I tried this in a code editor instead of in the browser and this answer is correct. Pasting code into the browser console doesn't add any white spaces, but doing it in my editor (VSCode) does.